# How to bind to a property of a class instantiated in the current class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have two clasess, `MainWindow` and `MainWindow_ViewModel`.

`MainWindow` is defined like so:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    static public MainWindow wn;
    public MainWindow_ViewModel mwvm;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        wn = this;
        mwvm = new MainWindow_ViewModel();
    }
}
```

MainWindow_ViewModel is defined like this:

```
class MainWindow_ViewModel
{
    private List<String> _filtros;
    public List<String> filtros
    {
        get
        {
            return _filtros;
        }
    }


    public MainWindow_ViewModel()
    {
        _filtros = new List<String>();
        _filtros.add("Filtro1");
        _filtros.add("Filtro2");
        _filtros.add("Filtro3");
    }
}
```

Notice that there is no static methods or properties whatsoever.

In MainWindow's XAML I have a ListBox that I want to bind with the `mwvm.filtros` which should be available directly from code-behind.

1. How can I achieve that WITHOUT using DataContext and only in XAML?
2. Could it be possible to bind from another class (i.e. another window) to the following path? `MainWindow.wn.mwvm.filtros`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course. You don't need C# code to bind the view model. Just create an object in the `DataContext` element:

```
<Window.DataContext>
   <local:MainWindow_ViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
```

You have to create a namespace for your local project though. Full code:

```
<Window x:Class="Your.Namespace.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Your.Namespace"
>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindow_ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
```

You can't bind from another `Window` or `Control` unless you pass it along or make it static. If it is sub control of this `Window`, you can set its data context.

Comment: I have no knowledge in WPF or XAML (so pardon my ignorance), but doesn't the OP state that he does not want to use DataContext?

Comment: Perfect answer, you just left out the Listbox definition/binding to filtros property

Comment: I thought it was just to achieve this, not to actually code the listbox. OP can find that easily everywhere on the web.

Comment: Matias Cicero is right. I don't want to use DataContext. The thing is that by applying that solution I'm creating a totally new MainWindow_ViewModel instance. I don't want that. I want to use the same instance in `MainWindow.wn.mwvm`.

Comment: Then assign the existing instance from your c# code.